# Make javascript-snippet affect 3 divs instead of 1

Tags: javascript, html

I have this very usefull little piece of javascript that centers mig div. By i would like to make it apply to 3 divs on the same site, without repeating the same piece of code 3 times.

Any ideas on how to do it?
Putting all 3 divs into 1 divs that takes care of it, is not and option.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    <!--
    function getWindowHeight() {
        var windowHeight = 0;
        if (typeof(window.innerHeight) == 'number') {
            windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        }
        else {
            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
                windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            }
            else {
                if (document.body && document.body.clientHeight) {
                    windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
                }
            }
        }
        return windowHeight;
    }
    function setContent() {
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var windowHeight = getWindowHeight();
            if (windowHeight > 0) {


            var contentElement = document.getElementById('outer');
                var contentHeight = contentElement.offsetHeight;

                if (windowHeight < 570) {
                    contentElement.style.position = 'relative';
                    contentElement.style.top = '30px';
                }
                else if (windowHeight - contentHeight > 0) {
                    contentElement.style.position = 'relative';
                    contentElement.style.top = ((windowHeight / 2) - (contentHeight / 2)) + 'px';
                }





                else {
                    contentElement.style.position = 'static';
                }   

            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        setContent();
    }
    window.onresize = function() {
        setContent();
    }
    //-->
    </script>
```

Regards Troels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check if `document.getElementById` exists. It has been supported since the Roman Empire.

Pass the id or the actual element that has to be centered to your function. That removes the dependency on a fixed element (`#outer`) in your case and makes it more flexible. Also try to name your functions to be indicative of what they are actually doing. `setContent` is a very generic name and doesn't indicate the centering aspect anywhere.

```
function centerElementWithId(id) {
    ..
    var contentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    ..
}
```

Then call it thrice,

```
centerElementWithId('outer')
centerElementWithId('secondDiv')
centerElementWithId('thirdDiv');
```